# Multiple "Select Case" statements into Aggregate Named Query using EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, case, jpql

I'm writing a simple query in my java code using eclipselink v2.3.
This query must simply return a String and two integers, nothing strange I think, or at least I thought,

The query I'm building is the following:

```
q = entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT new com.myclass.CalculationQueryResult(transits.device.name,"
        + " SUM(case when transits.direction = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ,"
        + " SUM(case when transits.direction = 0 then 1 else 0 end)) from Transits_Log transits "
        + " where transits.device.name in :devices and transits.dateTime >= :startDate"
        + " and transits.dateTime < :endDate group by transits.device.name" + " order by transits.device.name",
    CalculationQueryResult.class);
```

While it, obviuosly works in SQL Server (our native counterpart), this does not work in JPQL.
The two different `(SUM -> CASE)` clauses were strangely (at least for me that i'm quite new to JPA) equals to each other. So, I decided to take out the native SQL from the JPQL to investigate deeper and the problem was there. The generated SQL is this one:

```
SELECT t0.Name, 
    **SUM(CASE  WHEN (t1.Direction = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)** , 
    **SUM(CASE WHEN (t1.Direction = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)** FROM dbo.ZZZ t0,
    YYYY t1 
    WHERE ((((t1.DeviceName IN ('XXXXX')) 
    AND (t1.DateTime >= {ts '2012-09-24 17:26:48.031'})) 
    AND (t1.DateTime < {ts '2012-09-24 18:26:48.031'})) 
    AND (t0.Name = t1.DeviceName)) GROUP BY t0.Name 
    ORDER BY t0.Name ASC
```

As you can see, the SQL generated statement are wrong on the first two lines 'cause the first SUM and the second one should be one the opposite of the other while they're not.

Am I doing something extremely wrong? Does JPQL support multiple nested CASE and SUM? Are there any way to circumnavigate the error(if is the case) without having to write directly native SQL code?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have a similar kind of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177517/spring-jpa-repository-converter-not-found

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd.  Are you sure your JPQL is correct and compile/deployed?

Can you try the 2.4 release?

If it still occurs, please log a bug.

Comment: thanks for thinking the same as me. 
I do not think I have any error while compiling/deploying. I'm currently debugging the application directly on my eclipse/tomcat.
Just to be sure, are there any "cache file" (sorry but I'm a beginner with JPA) I have to delete? 

Then 'll try the 2.4 and post a bug if necessary.