# Spring JPA repository Converter not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an entity class `UserModel.java`

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode( of = { "id" } )
@ToString( of = { "id" } )
public class UserModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
@Column( name = "u_id" )
private Long id;

@Column( name = "u_first_name" )
private String firstName;

@Column( name = "u_last_name" )
private String lastName;

@Column( name = "u_email_id" )
private String emailId;

@Column( name = "u_password" )
private String password;

@Column( name = "u_mobile_number" )
private String mobileNumber;

@Column( name = "u_created_at" )
private Calendar createdAt;

@Column( name = "u_is_active" )
private Boolean isActive;

@Column( name = "u_reason" )
private String reason;


}
```

I need to fetch some statistics based on the values contained in each column. So I created a `JPQL` query and the result I am mapping to one more `Entity` class `UserStatisticsModel.java`

```
@Data
@Entity
public class UserStatisticsModel {

@Id
@Column
private Integer id;

@Column
private Integer activeUsers;

@Column
private Integer suspendedUsers;

@Column
private Integer removedUser;
}
```

I created a repository class to execute the query.

```
public interface UserStatisticsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserStatisticsModel, Integer> {

@Query( " Select sum(case when u.isActive is true then 1 else 0 end) as activeUsers, "
        + " sum(case when u.isSuspended is true then 1 else 0 end) as suspendedUsers, "
        + " sum(case when u.isActive is false then 1 else 0 end) as removedUser"
        + " from UserModel u " + " where u.accountStatus <>5" )
UserStatisticsModel getUserStatistics();
```

}

But on executing the query I am getting an exception. Although as per logs query is getting executed and the values are perfect, but mapping is failing.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.highpeak.tlp.datastore.model.UserStatisticsModel]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:324)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:206)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToObjectConverter.convert(ArrayToObjectConverter.java:66)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:37)
... 125 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone explain what is this error and how to fix it?

Available Solution:

1. I can create those fields in `UserModel.java` but I do not want to
   create those fields in that class.
2. I can also create a native query and it will work

**UPDATE**
If I change the return type of the query to `List<Integer>`, I am not getting any exceptions and I am getting proper result. But why can not I map those Integers to the fields of my `@Entity` class `UserStatisticsmodel.java`

Comment: It is telling you what the problem is: you haven't defined a converter to convert from an integer to a UserStatisticsModel.

Comment: You may also want to consider setting `nativeQuery=true` on the `@Query`, unless you're not doing that intentionally for some reason.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas How to define a converter?

Comment: It is not a native query. If I set it to true it will work. But I want to use `JPQL`

Comment: Has this ever been solved? I'm facing the same issue. My (native) SQL statement returns one row with 6 collums, they appear as Object[] Array in Java, then the ArrayToObjectConverter only takes the first collums and tries to convert that into my target type, which of course fails.

Comment: Okay, I fixed my problem. I got the exact same exception because of a type mismatch. I had a method TypeB selectQuery(...) within a JpaRepository<TypeA, String>. The error "converter not found" is not very helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is the issue. You say `Select 1 as id` but you want to return a `UserStatisticsModel`. So you'd have to fix your query or change the method signature to return an `Integer` instead.

Comment: `id` is a field in the class `UserStatisticsModel.java`. The `ORM` should map 1 as id right?

Comment: If I change the return type to `Integer`, I will get only one value, i.e, is the result of `sum(case when u.isActive is true then 1 else 0 end) as activeUsers`, then how can I get the values of the rest of the `aggregations` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned @Babajide M. Moibi, try changing your query to: **Select 1 as id**, sum(case when u.isActive is true then 1 else 0 end) as activeUsers....